# Does html5 support custom tags?

Tags: html

We all know HTML5 supports custom attributes, like:

```
<div data-name="some-value"></div>
```

But does it also support custom tags, like:

```
<mycustomtag data-id="some-value"></mycustomtag>
```

I have tried and it does not show any errors. Plus, I can make all 'mycustomtag' data font be bold using CSS:

```
mycustomtag { font-weight: bold; }
```

I know it's possible to manipulate custom tags using Javascript to achieve something I desire. Like I can make `<mycustomtag>` to be a ready-made table data with name and age. But is this allowed by W3 organizations? Or do they forbid to try these types of things.

Also, will it create any W3 validation errors?

Comment: The question is - **why** do you need custom tags?

Comment: Well it looks nice and unique, you know. Not that it's essential.

Comment: A quick search on google shows yes. Check out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Comment: @DutGRIFF with a side note that all new tag names MUST contain at least one dash. So the OP's example is not valid.